# Trying to code a 'String Is Numeric Of Type?' method through reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to write an overload for a typicall `IsNumeric?` function, my intention is to accomplish two tasks calling one function (and of course optimizing the code to accomplish the task in the better way and in few lines of code, I don't know if my approach should be the better way but It's what I'm trying):

> 1st: Determine if the string value is numeric.
>
> 2nd: Determine if the numeric value is of the apropiate DataType. (Integer, Long, etc...)
>   Long, etc...)

But I have two problems with this:

> 1st: The method "TryParse" is not found on the reflection search (I've tried a lot of binding combinations).
>
> 2nd: I don't know how to instance the DataType on the method
>   parameters (See: `{Value, New T}`)

Here is my code:

```
Private Function StringIsNumericOf(Of T)(ByVal Value As String) As Boolean

    Dim Method As MethodInfo =
    GetType(T).GetMethod("TryParse", BindingFlags.Public)

    If Method IsNot Nothing Then
        Return Method.Invoke(Me, BindingFlags.Public, Nothing,
                             New Object() {Value, New T}, 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Else
        MsgBox("Method not found.")
        Return Nothing

    End If

End Function
```

And here is an example usage of what I would like to expect:

```
    ' Expected result: False, it's a Double.
    MsgBox(StringIsNumericOf(Of Long)("50.1D"))

    ' Expected result: False, it's an Int64.
    MsgBox(StringIsNumericOf(Of Integer)("1L"))

    ' Expected result: True
    MsgBox(StringIsNumericOf(Of Long)(CStr(Long.MaxValue)))
```

> UPDATE:

Just a **failed** intent to solve the 1st problem, this is what I was trying:

```
    Dim Method As MethodInfo =
    GetType(T).GetMethod("TryParse",
                         BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static,
                         Type.DefaultBinder,
                         New Type() {GetType(String), GetType(T)},
                         New ParameterModifier() {})
```

Comment: When searching for `TryParse`, did you include the `Static` binding flag? - TryParse is a static method on the types, and used as `Integer.TryParse(...`

Comment: @Jon Egerton I didn't tried that Flag, now with your help I'm able to found the method but it throws an exception saying that an ambiguous method match is found, I suppose that this is because the TryParse method has an overload, but how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: You need to use `BindingFlags.Static` as well as `BindingFlags.Public`, as `TryParse` is a static method on the type.

Second problem, there are two versions of TryParse available. For example for integer there is:

[`public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out int result
)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and

[`public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out int result
)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To resolve this you have to pass in an array of types that matches the arguments to the overload you wish to invoke. In this case that is a `String`, and a `ByRef T`.

The following should bind the version you want:

```
    GetType(T).GetMethod("TryParse",
                         BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static,
                         Nothing,
                         New Type() {GetType(System.String), GetType(T).MakeByRefType()},
                         Nothing)
```

Comment: `MakeByRefType()` wow, just an awesome Reflection knowledge hehe. that ByRef param is where I was failing in my last intent, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just this is how looks the final work, thanks to @**Jon Egerton** answer.

```
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether an String is a valid numeric of the given type.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">Indicates the numeric DataType</typeparam>
''' <param name="Value">Indicates the string value.</param>
''' <returns>
''' <c>true</c> if string is a valid numeric of the given type, <c>false</c> otherwise.
''' </returns>
''' <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
Private Function StringIsNumeric(Of T)(ByVal Value As String) As Boolean

    Const MethodName As String = "TryParse"
    Dim Result As Object = Nothing

    Dim Method As MethodInfo =
    GetType(T).GetMethod(MethodName,
                         BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static,
                         Type.DefaultBinder,
                         New Type() {GetType(String), GetType(T).MakeByRefType()},
                         New ParameterModifier() {})

    If Method IsNot Nothing Then
        Return Method.Invoke(Me, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static,
                             Type.DefaultBinder,
                             New Object() {Value, Result},
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Else
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("Method '{0}' not found on '{1}' Type.",
                                          MethodName, GetType(T).Name))
        Return Nothing

    End If

End Function
```